# Continuity of composition implies continuity of function itself

Tags: general-topology, continuity

There are 2 relating question to this :

1. Let $X, Y, Z$ be a topological spaces. Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ be such that $F = g \circ f$ and $f$ are continuous on $X$.

If $f$ is an open map and surjective, then $g$ is also continuous.

**Proof** Let $O$ be an open set in $Z$. Then $F^{-1}(Z)$ is open in $X$. So $f(F^{-1}(Z))$ is open in $Y$. But $g^{-1}(Z) = f(F^{-1}(Z))$ (by surjectivity of $f$). The proof is done.

What if $X, Y$ are metric spaces now, then can the openness be dropped ?

2. Let $X, Y, Z$ be a topological spaces. Assume that $X$ and $Y$ are metrizable with the metrics $d_X$ and $d_Y$. Let $f : X \rightarrow Y$ and $g : Y \rightarrow Z$ be such that $F = g \circ f$ and $f$ are continuous on $X$.

If $f$ is surjective, then $g$ is continuous on $Y$.

**Proof** Let $y \in Y$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists $x \in X$ such that $$F(x) = g \circ f(x) = g(y).$$ Notice that $X$ is open and $f(X) = Y$ is also open.

**I try to conclude that $g(y) = F(x)$ on some neighborhood of $y$, and since $F$ is continuous on any subset $A$ of $X$, this seem to be ok.**

But I am not sure that the second one sounds to be ok as I expected. And if the proof does not ok, does the statement 2 still holds ? Or which additional conditions should be made (instead of forcing $f$ to be open)?

Comment: $Y$ needs to have the final topology, which means (if I'm not wrong) that $f$ needs to be onto and satisfy the following: a set $V\subset Y$ is open if and only if $f^{1}(V)$ is open in $X$.

Answer (score 0):

1.) No, it can't be dropped. Consider X to be a discrete space, which is metric with the discrete metric. Then, any $F$ will be continuous, because any function from a discrete space is continuous, so any $g$ (including a non-continuous $g$) would suffice

2.) Where does the $g$ being surjective from the first line of the proof come from?

Comment: It is $f$, the $g$ is a typo.

Comment: Even so, it is not clear to me what you are trying to do in the proof. It does not matter, though, because as I said, the conditions of surjectivity and metrizability alone are not enough because of the counterexample provided